# How do I properly set up Visual Studio C++ projects on GitHub?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github

I need GitHub for syncing my project between two PCs that I'm working on. So that changes I commit and push could be easily pulled from another PC. I set up a GitHub repository, pushed my project to it and all works wonderfully until the second PC comes in. I clone the repo to second PC and when I press build hundreds of errors come up, mostly about being unable to open different source .h files. However if I just copy the code and create a project locally everything works. I can't understand whats the problem, could it be that PC have different paths to project folders? Or do I just do something wrong setting up the repo?

Also the first PC is running Win7 and the second is running Win10 if that's of any importance. Both have most up-to-date Visual Studio community.

Comment: I prefer to use `CMake` to generate my projects and use out of source building so that nothing generated (including the Visual Studio project file) is stored in the repository. I use this on dozens of machines between work and home.

Comment: @drescherjm I can see that working but it looks more like avoiding the issue rather than solving it. Though will consider this, thanks.

Comment: It's not directly for this single feature alone. We build with multiple different compilers and use other `CMake` features like unit testing and installers and certainly the package management. Although all of this takes a lot of time to learn and use effectively.

Comment: To solve your problem you probably have to make sure that you use the exact same compiler version and the same SDK version. And keep all externa, libraries in the same locations. For the last 2 decades I have built my code from X: for that very reason. I can create an X: on all computers pretty easily and have that be the root of my programming trees. This `X:` also helped me quite a bit with remote debugging. Although I don't do so much of that recently. I used to have to do remote debugging for directx code which is difficult to debug locally.

Comment: @drescherjm Alright, I tried moving project files to same location on both PCs and it worked. Though there was a prompt about different windows SDK versions, but that is easily fixed. Seems quite dumb that such thing as project location can cause such troubles though. Thank you for help. You might want to post this as an answer so I can flag is as solution?

Answer (score 0):

> hundreds of errors come up, mostly about being unable to open different source .h file

Sounds like dependency files are located in different locations in different PCs.

You could use relative path with macros like `$(ProjectDir)`, `$(SolutionDir)`, `$(ProgramFiles)`, `$(WindowsSdkDir)`, `$(Path)` etc to configure include and library directories  in VS project properties.